# Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1; query: SELECT overlay_mutation, largest_batch_id FROM document_overlays WHERE uid =

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7El3s.png)
i am suffering from this while uploading user_name to firestore

fun uploadUserName(userName: String, _passUserNameUploadStatus: MutableStateFlow) {
fireStore.collection(USER_COLLECTION)
.document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
.set(
hashMapOf(USER_NAME to userName)

```
        )
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                _passUserNameUploadStatus.emit(USER_NAME_SAVED_SUCCESSFULLY)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                _passUserNameUploadStatus.emit(it.message.toString() + "this is error")
            }
        }
}--
```

(this is my function to add username to the firestore in the document named uid of the current user---

but it is throwing the sqllite error that is row is too big to fit into cursor window

the twist is that i am not handling the queries because they are made by firestore)